# Webkit from opensource.apple.com

Tags: webkit

What do I need to compile webkit from sources available @ opensource.apple.com? I checked out current revision from SVN, then downloaded webcore/javascriptcore/javascriptglue tarballs from opensource.apple.com, extracted them and substituted directories in local SVN repo, but build fails with errors in javascriptcore :(

Is this the correct process, or am I doing something wrong?

--
Edit:

Hmm. Maybe I should've stated my question in a different way. I want to be able to debug Safari installed on my system, with GDB. I'm able to build revisions downloaded from SVN repo, but I don't know which revision  was used to build Safari on my system (I need to debug this specific version). That's why I tried downloading source from opensource.apple.com, but with no success :(

Answer (score 0):

I've never built webkit before, but here's what I would do.  Hopefully it'll push you in the right direction:

Take a look at an archlinux [PKGBUILD](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libwebkit-git/PKGBUILD) for webkit.  It'll show you the commands executed to build it as well as the dependencies.  They should give you an idea of what you need to do, regardless of what distro you're using.  The link provided is for webkit from webkit.org, not apple.com.  I don't know how (or if) they differ.

I hope that helps (even a little). :-)